# What's wrong with this Java HashMap?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

Here is my code to place ArrayLists into the hashmap:

```
public static HashMap<String, ArrayList> keyword_map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList>();

ArrayList<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>();
keys.add("cat");
keys.add("sheep");
keys.add("dog");
keys.add("pig");
keys.add("cow");
keyword_map.put("animals", keys);
```

When i try to print the entry set and get an ArrayList from key "animals" like so:

```
ArrayList<String> related_keys = keyword_map.get("animals");
```

Nothing is returned. What am i doing wrong?

**For each key in the map, i want to store multiple values.**

How else can i do this/and or what am doing wrong?

Comment: Post a complete and runnable example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: okay. give me a min or two.

Comment: Apache Commons Collections has a map that holds a collection of values against each key.  See https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html.

Comment: take 2 or 3 ... and you will realize that you have a problem in another part of the code :D

Comment: The code you have posted does not exhibit the behaviour you describe. What makes you think it does? What exactly do you mean by 'nothing is returned'?

Comment: recommending apache commons anything in 2014 when Google Guava exists is criminal, your keyboard should be taken away!

Comment: I don't see a problem with your code.  But please note that `keyword_map.put("animals", keys);` will put a reference to your `ArrayList` into the map, not a copy of the array.  So if you later clear out or change your `ArrayList`, the value that you get with `keyword_map.get` will also change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This is proper idiomatic code and works just fine.

```
public static final Map<String, List<String>> MAP = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

public static void main(@Nonnull final String[] args)
{
    final List<String> animals = new ArrayList<String>();
    animals.add("cat");
    animals.add("sheep");
    animals.add("dog");
    animals.add("pig");
    animals.add("cow");
    MAP.put("animals", animals);
    System.out.println(MAP);
    final List<String> al = MAP.get("animals");
    System.out.println(al);
}
```

#### It outputs

```
{animals=[cat, sheep, dog, pig, cow]}
[cat, sheep, dog, pig, cow]
```

#### What are you expecting?

Comment: not sure what was wrong with my previous code, but the class is rather large and something was wrong..i replaced the list and map with your example and it works fine now.